# How do I pronounce “PER”?

Tags: pronunciation

PER (Price Earnings Ratio)

How would you say this out loud?

Pee-Ee-Ar or just 'per'?

Comment: Just reading this on the screen right now, I would say, "per," but it probably depends on the sentence and context and almost more importantly, whatever you guys use around the office.

Comment: To close-voters. This not a opinion-based issue.  The acronym  has a precise and common pronunciation  in financial contexts. Different pronunciations would be misunderstood or sound unusual.

Comment: I have rarely encountered *PER*; *P/E* or *PE* is more common.

Answer (score 25):

The more common pronunciation used in financial contexts is *(pee-ee ratio*)   ***[/ˌpiː iː ˈreɪʃiːəʊ/](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/p-e-ratio)*** also often written ***[P/E ratio](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/price-earningsratio.asp)***:

> - The price-earnings ratio (P/E Ratio) is the ratio for valuing a company that measures its current share price relative to its per-share earnings.

([www.investopedia.com](http://www.investopedia.com))

You can hear its usage and pronunciation in the following video ***[P/E Ratio](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=TKk1xdTbOK0)***

***[The history of price to earnings ratio](http://www.moneycontrol.com/news/investing/retracinghistoryprice-to-earnings-ratio_1019586.html):***

> - “The P/E ratio is today the most commonly used valuation metric in the world.” --- Prof. Janette Rutterford, Open University. ***The P/E has a long history, but it has not always been the most popular way to value shares.***  Since the invention of stock markets up until less than 100 years ago, the dividend yield (DY) was the main figure every investor was interested in. The asset backing behind a company was also important. The P/E is, compared to those two, a relatively recent invention. Even ***the phrase ‘price earnings ratio’ only became popular in the 1920s in the US.*** In the UK dividends were still what mattered up until the mid-1960s.

([www.moneycontrol.com](http://www.moneycontrol.com))